# Xubuntu after new installation booting from old disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, xubuntu

I have installed a new version of Xubuntu 16.04 LTS on a new SSD disk. I left the old version on the old HDD disk to copy some data. After installing the new OS I detached the old disk and now I can't boot my Linux. There is a blank screen. But when I connect the old HDD back, Linux is booting and I can see GRUB. I don't need the old disk and I want to disconnect it permanently, but how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after booting to the old hdds xubuntu install grub2s MBR on the new hard disk using this command:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
```

`/dev/sdb` has to be replaced with the device node of your ssd

Comment: You are most welcome